# Xcode bot custom script output

Tags: xcode, xcode6, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

When running an Xcode bot that has custom scripts, none of the output (from the echo command) is shown on the integration progress (see screenshot below). It can only be seen in the build log once it is completed.

[image]

Is it possible to replace "Running 1 of 1 custom shell scripts" with output from said script?

Comment: I filed a radar with this request, if you or anyone else would like to dupe: rdar://20433269 (http://openradar.appspot.com/20433269)